# GADInvalidInitializationException without Installing GoogleMobileAds SDK iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, ads

I am building a react-native app which I do not intend to display ads but I have Firebase Authentication and other related services. To my surprise I keep getting this error below. What could have happen?

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK 
was initialized incorrectly. Google AdMob publishers should follow 
instructions here: https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios- 
update-plist to include the AppMeasurement framework, set the -ObjC 
linker flag, and set GADApplicationIdentifier with a valid App ID. 
Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here: 
https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist'
```

The way I [found](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-ios/issues/58) around this error is to update the info.plist by adding

```
 <key>GADIsAdManagerApp</key>
 <true/>
```

This solved the error issue but not the fundamental problem which is why should it required GAD Application Identifier since ads will not be displayed in the app.